# java client throwing SSLHandshakeException connecting to AWS ELB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, wireshark, amazon-elb

My java client throws `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake` while connecting to AWS ELB. I took a pcap file on the client side and analyzed with wireshark. The SSL handshake looks to be successful because I can see 2 Application Data packets transferred encrypted (first one from client and second one from server). But java thinks the SSLHandshake failed. Even my ELB logs don't show any connections from the client IP. Is wireshark interpreting the packets wrongly here? Or is it a problem with AWS ELB or java itself?

My client is running java 1.7.0_25 and there is no option to update it. The server doesn't require a client certificate.

Comment: have you saved the wireshark log ? If you did can you please add it

Comment: You can analyse logging by enabling debug flag in jvm  ie  -Djavax.net.debug=all